# Why do I get a memory error only for std::string?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create my own vector class. It seems to work fine for the built-in types, but when using `std::string` as a parameter, the program shows me the error below after entering two strings. I have no experience with debuggers yet. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
a.out(21360,0x109f1de00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe4f8405b68: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(21360,0x109f1de00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

This is my code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class vector {
    std::size_t sz{0};
    T* ptr{nullptr};
public:
    vector<T>() { }
    vector<T>(std::size_t m_sz) : sz(m_sz) {
        ptr = new T[m_sz];
        sz = m_sz;
    }

    ~vector() {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
public:
    T operator[](std::size_t n) {
        if (n < sz)
            return ptr[n];
        throw std::out_of_range(std::string("element [") + std::to_string(n) + "] does not exist");
    }
public:
    T* begin() { return sz ? ptr : nullptr; }
    T* end() { return sz ? ptr + sz : nullptr; }
    bool empty() { return !sz; }
    std::size_t size() { return sz; }
    inline void push_back(T);
};

template<class T>
void vector<T>::push_back(T x) {
    T* tmp_ptr = ptr;
    ptr = new T[sz + 1];
    for (std::size_t i(0); sz && i != sz; ++i)
            ptr[i] = tmp_ptr[i];
    if (tmp_ptr)
        delete tmp_ptr;
    ptr[sz] = x;
    ++sz;
}

int main() {
    vector<std::string> vect;
    for (std::string str; std::cin >> str;)
        vect.push_back(str);
    for (std::string& str : vect)
        std::cout << str << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem: You use `new[]` but `delete` instead of `delete[]`.

Comment: In `operator[]` you likely meant `if(n < sz)` and not `if(sz)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo nice catch! Unfortunately, it is not the cause of this error.

Comment: @L.S.Roth You also need up update `delete tmp_ptr;`. Not just the `delete[]` in the destructor.

Comment: `if (tmp_ptr) { } delete tmp_ptr;` is a typo. It should be `if (tmp_ptr) { delete tmp_ptr; }`

Comment: @jabaa Luckily the behavior is identical to the intended code. The `if` is redundant as `delete nullptr;` is required to do nothing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux should be `if (sz && n < sz)` then, right?

Comment: @L.S.Roth Since `sz` and `n` are unsigned, if `sz` is zero there is no possible value of `n` that is less than zero. So `sz && n < sz` is identical to `n < sz` in this case.

Comment: I would like to propose you to check for `nullptr != ptr` instead of `0 < sz` in your `begin()`, `end()` and `empty()` functions to make sure allocation succeeded in your constructor (even though technically this shouldn't be a problem anymore nowadays).

Comment: @taiBsu You shouldn't need any check at all for the iterators. If you just always return `ptr` and `ptr + sz` either you get the intended iterators for a valid range, or you return `nullptr` and `nullptr + 0` which is equivalent to the current code.

Comment: It's all the (or at least multiple) bugs mentioned in the comments together. After I fixed them it works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/u4Qick59NeT2k4Eu

Comment: I would also suggest using `i < sz` instead of `sz && i != sz` in the `for` loop of `push_back()`.  And also, make `push_back()` take its input by const reference. Otherwise, if you want to keep passing in the parameter by value then implement move semantics to move the parameter into the array instead of copying it.

Comment: @L.S.Roth please be a bit more precise here. what doesn't work?

Comment: @L.S.Roth It is likely the code you've shown isn't identical to what you are using. Although it is possible that the problem is due to UB and nobody can reproduce it due to very bad luck, please make sure the *exact* code you are sharing reproduces the problem for you. Read about [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `delete[]` what you `new[]` (everywhere).

Both your destructor and `push_back` causes *undefined behavior*.

Your `push_back` should look something like this:

```
template<class T>
void vector<T>::push_back(T x) {
    T* old_ptr = ptr;
    ptr = new T[sz + 1];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) // corrected loop condition
        ptr[i] = old_ptr[i];  
    delete[] old_ptr;   // no need to check if it's `nullptr`, but delete[]
    ptr[sz] = x;
    ++sz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `push_back` function has a small typo:

```
if (tmp_ptr)
    delete tmp_ptr;
```

should be

```
delete[] tmp_ptr;
```

Comment: Should be just `delete[] tmp_ptr;` by itself, no need to check for `nullptr` since `delete` will handle that for you.